# How to use semantic ui "set values" and onChange event together

Tags: javascript, drop-down-menu, semantic-ui

I'm having a hard time figuring out how to add behaviour and onChange event.

Here's the jsfiddle on how I'm doing it but it doesn't work: https://jsfiddle.net/pbfqzvch/9/

```
$('select.dropdown').dropdown({
    'set selected': ['angular'],
  onChange: function(value, text, $selectedItem) {
      alert('hello');
    }
})
```

Comment: The code from your question works - https://jsfiddle.net/pbfqzvch/10/

Comment: What is the desired functionality with the code provided in the question?

Comment: On load, i would like to select an option by default ('angular') then I have some extra codes on the `onChange` function. Right now, the `onChange` works but it doesn't give me the selected value i put.

Comment: onChange does provide the right value. As for the default selection you can add the `selected` property to your option - https://jsfiddle.net/pbfqzvch/12/

Comment: Thanks! This should be my last resort, i assume semantic should have a better way to do this since the settings are all written in their documentation, it's just, i don't know how to put them together.

Comment: Looking through their documentation it seems to be a known bug so you either can access the value programatically on change or set the default starting value but not both. I would leave the onChange event handler and just use `selected` on the desired element - it is still semantically correct!